# getting error when window.tapstream.fireEvent called

Tags: angularjs, cordova

i am getting error when i call  `window.tapstream.fireEvent('test-event', false);`

error given below
Error: window.tapstream is undefined
@ angular.min.js:37:94

i am using one page phonegap app when i change route so controller change then it generate error  window.tapstream is undefined  in angulerjs

Answer (score 0):

in model

```
app.factory('deviceReady', function(){
    return function() {
        if (typeof window.tapstream === 'object') {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
                window.tapstream.create('TAPSTREAM_ACCOUNT_NAME', 'TAPSTREAM_SDK_SECRET', {
                    idfa: '<IDFA goes here>'
                });

            }, false);
        } else {

        }
    };
});
```

in controller

```
 if (typeof window.tapstream === 'object') {

            window.tapstream.fireEvent('accountCreated-page', false);
        }
```